# Bubbles disappeared after converting d3v3 to d3v4

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am trying to build a bubble chart using d3. Everything was good in d3 v3. But after changed to d3 v4, the bubbles disappeared. It seems the code below doesn't work in v4. The function "value" was changed to some other things.

```
pack = d3.pack()
    .padding(2)
    .size([this.diameter - this.margin, this.diameter - this.margin])
    .value(function (d) { return d.size; });
```

Here is a sample in D3 V3. How to change it to d3 v4?
https://embed.plnkr.co/qM3qrk3swvalQFBh1Db1/

Thank you!

Comment: Mike has a great v4 example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535)

Comment: Thank you! I solved my problem. Just changed several lines. The main different is  `root = d3.hierarchy(root)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });`

Comment: awesome! Consider posting your answer and accepting it below so others can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ".value" can't be used in d3v4. It needs to be changed to:

```
  let pack = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
    .padding(2);
```

In order to get nodes, you need to use `pack(root).descendants()`. For the root, get it from the d3.hierarchy. Hope this will help someone.

```
  let root = d3.hierarchy(root)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  let nodes = pack(root).descendants();
```